# on() doesn't recognize a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a problem with `on()`. Here is my code:

```
<span class="add" id="id_foo" >add this stuff</span>
```

```js
$(".add").on('click', function() {
    $.post("/toto.com/add.php", { trainning: this.id }, function() {});
    $(this).html("Remove this stuff");
    $(this).removeClass("add").addClass("remove");
    //alert($(this).attr("class"));-->give the good class
});

$(".remove").on('click', function() {
    //doesn't work
    $.post("/toto.com/remove.php", { trainning: this.id }, function() {});
    $(this).html("add this stuff");
    $(this).removeClass("remove").addClass("add");
});
```

The selector for the class `remove` doesn't recognize it whereas when I click on the button with the `add` class, the class is changing. Do you know what the problem is?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try placing your jQuery inside of the DOM ready. `$( document ).ready(function() {
//Place all jQuery here.....
});`

Comment: This should work `$(document).on('click', '.remove', function()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use delegated event handlers as you're dynamically changing the classes the handlers are attached to. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".add", function() {
    $.post("/toto.com/add.php", { trainning: this.id });
    $(this).html("Remove this stuff").toggleClass("add remove");    
});

$(document).on('click', ".remove", function() {
    $.post("/toto.com/remove.php", { trainning: this.id });
    $(this).html("add this stuff").toggleClass("remove add");
});
```

Depending on the location of the `script` tag this JS code is in you may also need to wrap your code in a document.ready handler. If it's just before the `</body>` tag it will work fine, if it's in the head, place it inside `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`